# How do I get the 8-hour cumulative TWAP of 1-min candles on Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I'm creating an indicator that takes the 8-hour cumulative TWAP of 1-min candles, which will be reset every 8 hours. This should be able to be shown on all time frames. Is this the right way to do so?

```
resIn        = input("480", "Resolution")
res          = resIn == "0" ? '1' : resIn
typicalPrice = ohlc4
weight       = barssince(change(security))
price        = 0.0

price       := weight == 0 ? typicalPrice : typicalPrice + nz(price[1])
twap         = price / (weight + 1)
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You were close )

```
//@version=4
study("8H VWAP")
resIn        = input("480", "Resolution")
typicalPrice = ohlc4
reset        = change(time(resIn))
weight       = barssince(reset)
price        = 0.0

price       := weight == 0 ? typicalPrice : typicalPrice + nz(price[1])
twap         = price / (weight + 1)

plot(twap)
bgcolor(reset ? color.gray : na)
```

[image]